# How to make rust macro optional token produce code when not present?

Tags: rust, macros, rust-macros

Here is the classic situation :

```rust
macro_rules! foo {
    ($a:tt $(b:tt)?) => {
        do_something_with_a($a);
        $(do_something_with_b($b);)?
    }
}
```

But what if you want this:

```rust
macro_rules! foo {
    ($a:tt) => {
        do_something_with_a($a);
        do_something_when_b_is_absent();
    }
    ($a:tt b:tt) => {
        do_something_with_a($a);
        do_something_with_b($b);
    }
}
```

### How to avoid code repetition here ?

Is there a way to do something like:

```rust
macro_rules! foo {
    ($a:tt $(b:tt)?) => {
        do_something_with_a($a);
        $(do_something_with_b($b);)?
        ${if(
            eq(count(b), 0),
            {do_something_when_b_is_absent();}
        )}
    }
}
```

My guess is no, but I could be surprised :)

Comment: Surely this is a procedural macro to do that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this using `@internal` to differentiate between the 2 cases,
or use a different macro for the other cases:

```rust
macro_rules! foo {
    (@internal ) => {
        do_something_when_b_is_absent();
    };
    (@internal $b:tt) => {
        do_something_with_b($b);
    };
    ($a:tt $($b:tt)?) => {
        do_something_with_a($a);
        foo!(@internal $($b)?);
    };
}
```

Comment: `@some_random_description` is common for internal macro rules.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out, it is possible to write a macro that does the magic:

```rust
macro_rules! if_not {
    (() $code:block) => {
        $code
    };
    (($($target:tt)+) $code:block) => {};
}
```

Then you use it this way:

```rust
macro_rules! foo {
    ($a:tt $(b:tt)?) => {
        do_something_with_a($a);
        $(do_something_with_b($b);)?
        if_not!(($(b)?) {
            do_something_when_b_is_absent();
        });
    }
}
```